# How to join an external table to a set of polygons, and symbolize on the joined values, in a web map?

Tags: web-mapping, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, attribute-joins

Say I have a table showing a number of statistics - for example, various [gun crime by US State](http://www.guardian.co.uk/news/datablog/2011/jan/10/gun-crime-us-state#data) measures. I also have a dataset of [state boundaries](http://servicesbeta4.esri.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/5).

How can I join the table to the features in a web map, and symbolize the polygons using attributes from the table? The joined table must be specified within the web application (rather than hard-coded via ArcMap) since the statistics will be derived on-the-fly and will be specific to each user.

I need the ability to change the symbology on-the-fly, for example by choosing a different crime statistic to map, in which case the map should update immediately.

**ArcGIS Server**

Using ArcGIS Server 10.1 the [REST API supports table joins](http://traffic.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/sdk/rest/index.html?layer.html). Are there any sample scripts which step through how to set this up?

**Other environments?**

Can the same thing be achieved using FOSS software?

Thanks. (This is a modified version of my [earlier question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19351/what-server-and-api-to-use-for-displaying-complex-polygons-with-dynamic-symbolog) since that hasn't yet received any responses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the API supports a "Query table data source" with query element.  So you should be able use a SQL statement to handle the join and summarize the data with a group by clause.  Something along the lines of this:

```
select st.*, gc."Handguns murders" as hg_murders
from states as st
    inner join gun_crimes as gc on gc.State=st.STATE_NAME
```

As for FOSS, OGR has a stripped down [SQL](https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html) syntax that can perform table joins.  You could set this up in [virtual format](https://gdal.org/ogr/drv_vrt.html) pulling data from a variety of underlying data sources.

Comment: thanks @tharen. Do you know of any samples showing how to do this? I'm experienced with the AGS JavaScript API but have no experience whatsoever with using the REST API directly, so I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Drilling down into the [docs](http://traffic.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/sdk/rest/dataSource.html) there is an example setting up a datasource using both the SQL method and also setting up a join datasource.  Other than that I'm not sure where to point you. A SQL join should work if you have the tables in a database.  Note I modified the example assuming the geometry was in the states table.

Comment: @StephenLead, have you got any solution for this. As I am also searching for the same. Can you guide me?